# Too many errors emitted, stopping now - Issues with XCode 7 and Cocos2d-x 2.2.6 - C++11

Tags: ios, objective-c, c++11, cocos2d-x, xcode7

I really need some help on this. I have currently migrated my cocos2d-x project to a newer version of Cocos2D and I've got everything ok, but for now, I'm stucked into something that I'm not able to solve it by myself.

My project is all overwritten to C++11 and looks like it is not able to compile iOS Libraries as they use Objective-C.

My project has the following settings, in the Build Settings:

- Under Linking -> Link with Standard Libraries -> NO
- Under Apple LLVM7.0 - Language -> C Language Dialect -> Compiler Default
- Under Apple LLVM7.0 - Language -> Compile Sources As -> According To File Type
- Under Apple LLVM7.0 - Language - C++ -> C++ Language Dialect -> C++11[-std=C++11]
- Under Apple LLVM7.0 - Language - C++ -> C++ Standard Library -> Compiler Default

And the error that is being displayed is the following:

```
In file included from /Users/guifranchi/Desktop/Projetos de Games/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/NewFlappyThatBalloon/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/guifranchi/Desktop/Projetos de Games/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/NewFlappyThatBalloon/Classes/AppDelegate.h:5:
In file included from /Users/guifranchi/Desktop/Projetos de Games/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/NewFlappyThatBalloon/proj.ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAds.h:7:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObjCRuntime.h:435:1: error: expected unqualified-id
@class NSString, Protocol;
^
                                                       ^
In file included from /Users/guifranchi/Desktop/Projetos de Games/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/NewFlappyThatBalloon/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/guifranchi/Desktop/Projetos de Games/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/NewFlappyThatBalloon/Classes/AppDelegate.h:5:
In file included from /Users/guifranchi/Desktop/Projetos de Games/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/NewFlappyThatBalloon/proj.ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAds.h:7:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:10:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:8:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:8:1: error: expected unqualified-id
@class NSString;
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:18:64: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT void NSSetZoneName(NSZone * __nullable zone, NSString *name)NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("Zone-based memory management is unavailable");
                                                               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSZone.h:19:19: error: unknown type name 'NSString'
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *NSZoneName(NSZone * __nullable zone) NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("Zone-based memory management is unavailable");
                  ^
In file included from /Users/guifranchi/Desktop/Projetos de Games/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/NewFlappyThatBalloon/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/guifranchi/Desktop/Projetos de Games/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/NewFlappyThatBalloon/Classes/AppDelegate.h:5:
In file included from /Users/guifranchi/Desktop/Projetos de Games/cocos2d-x-2.2.6/projects/NewFlappyThatBalloon/proj.ios/GoogleMobileAds.framework/Headers/GoogleMobileAds.h:7:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:10:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSArray.h:5:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:10:1: error: expected unqualified-id
@class NSInvocation, NSMethodSignature, NSCoder, NSString, NSEnumerator;
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:11:1: error: expected unqualified-id
@class Protocol;
^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSObject.h:17:1: error: expected unqualified-id
@protocol NSCopying
^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?